# problem with setLabelTable method to customize JSlider's lables

Tags: java, swing, jslider

According to this [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html#labels), one should do the following to customize JSlider's lables:

```
JSlider framesPerSecond = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL,
                                      FPS_MIN, FPS_MAX, FPS_INIT);
framesPerSecond.addChangeListener(this);
framesPerSecond.setMajorTickSpacing(10);
framesPerSecond.setPaintTicks(true);

//Create the label table
Hashtable labelTable = new Hashtable();
labelTable.put( new Integer( 0 ), new JLabel("Stop") );
labelTable.put( new Integer( FPS_MAX/10 ), new JLabel("Slow") );
labelTable.put( new Integer( FPS_MAX ), new JLabel("Fast") );
framesPerSecond.setLabelTable( labelTable ); //ERROR

framesPerSecond.setPaintLabels(true);
```

Actually Eclipse complain that setLabelTable want's a Dictionary not a HashTable ( I'm using sun sdk 1.6.0_25). The error is the following:

> The method setLabelTable(Dictionary)
>   in the type JSlider is not applicable
>   for the arguments   (Hashtable)

All the examples I found over Internet tells me to do like that.

So, what's the problem?

EDIT:

my question was wrong. It was just an include error. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I just commented Dictionary is supperclass of HashTable and you can put HashTable setLabelTabel, but if eclipse shows you this error we can think about two cases :

- you are not using java.util.Hashtable
- you are not using javax.swing.JSlider

I think the first is your problem just chek it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not absolutely sure, but it might work to simply replace `Hashtable` with `Dictionary`, which apparently is what the method wants.

```java
Dictionary labelTable = new Dictionary();
labelTable.put(new Integer(0), new JLabel("Stop"));
labelTable.put(new Integer(FPS_MAX / 10), new JLabel("Slow"));
labelTable.put(new Integer(FPS_MAX), new JLabel("Fast"));
framesPerSecond.setLabelTabel(labelTable);
```

Comment: Also Eclipse could miss the generics, you can try
Hashtable<Integer, JLabel> labelTable = new Hashtable<Integer, JLabel>();

or

Dictionary<Integer, JLabel> labelTable = new Hashtable<Integer, JLabel>();

Comment: Anyway I'm using Java 1.6.0_23 and Eclipse Helios SR1 and I don't get the error on the posted code..

Comment: Dictionary is supperclass of HashTable and your variant the same as previous

Comment: +1 Sorry, I overlooked your suggested generic declaration before. One essential virtue is exposing type errors such as this.

Answer (score 1):

Oh..thank you both @Ninto and @Sorceror. You are right. 
It was an include error:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.Hashtable;
```

instead of :

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
```